# How to notify client of block commit and/or transaction status using events in HLF?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, event-listener, hyperledger-chaincode

I am working on a client that needs to be notified of the status of any given blockchain transaction. To that end I am learning how to make use of events to achieve this. I tried referring to the official documentation on events in HLF 1.4 (found [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/peer_event_services.html)) but the link to the SDK documentation is dead. I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769741/how-do-i-notify-the-client-application-when-a-chaincode-is-invoked) but the provided links are all dead as well.

Then I came across the Fabric Gateway implementation (mentioned [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java)), and I found [BlockListenerTest](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/impl/BlockListenerTest.java), which forms the basis for this question.

---

My current scratch code looks like this:

```
BlockEventSourceFactory factory = BlockEventSourceFactory.getInstance();
BlockEventSource blockEventSource = factory.newBlockEventSource(channel);
blockEventSource.addBlockListener(blockEvent -> {
    System.out.println("[zzzzz] Block number is " + blockEvent.getBlockNumber());
});
channel.sendTransaction(responses);
blockEventSource.close();
```

In my Java chaincode, I call `stub.setEvent("myEventName", null)` to set events.

Problem is, I'm not seeing my debugging output, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could direct me to the correct resources to refer to, and/or help me make the code above work somehow.

---

(If there's any other information I should provide, please let me know via the comments and I will add them here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the high level Gateway SDK, you need to start by creating a Gateway object, then get a network object from that (use the sample code [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/release-1.4/) as a start).  From the network object, you can invoke [addBlockListener()](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/release-1.4/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/Network.html#addBlockListener-java.util.function.Consumer-) passing in your consumer function.  Then when you invoke submitTransaction on your contract object, your listener should get invoked.

In terms of tests, you're probably better off looking at the scenario test code [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway-java/blob/master/src/test/java/scenario/ScenarioSteps.java#L86), [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway-java/blob/master/src/test/java/scenario/ScenarioSteps.java#L342) and [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway-java/blob/master/src/test/java/scenario/ScenarioSteps.java#L631) for examples of usage.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried referring to the official documentation on events in HLF 1.4 (found here) but the link to the SDK documentation is dead. I also found this question but the provided links are all dead as well.

I checked in [fabric-sdk-node docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/master/docs). I found there are three tutorials about events who may help you to solve your problem. They are [transaction-commit-events.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/docs/tutorials/transaction-commit-events.md), [eventcheckpointer.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/docs/tutorials/event-checkpointer.md.ignore) and [Listeningtoevents.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/docs/tutorials/listening-to-events.md.ignore).

1. [Transaction-commit-events](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/docs/tutorials/transaction-commit-events.md) provides a special section with title "Event handling strategies".
2. [Eventcheckpointer.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/docs/tutorials/event-checkpointer.md.ignore) gives an approach to replay missed events emitted by peers, It also gives an overview of emmited events.
3. [Listeningtoevents.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/docs/tutorials/listening-to-events.md.ignore) also contains a section which talks about Events. It also gives the explanations about three different types of events.

I hope these three files could help you to solve your problem and master HLF.

**Bonus:** 
Fabric community is amazing. Make sure to join this [Fabric-SDK channel](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk) or check other [fabric chat channels](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/fabric/Hyperledger+Fabric) (see chat section).